# Unity touch input for Rolling Sky x axis control

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have written some code that I would image would be a very simplistic version of something found in the player controller of a game like Rolling Sky.

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        NewX = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition).x;
        float xMotion = (LastX - NewX) * -NavigationMultiplier / Screen.width;
        this.transform.position = new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x + xMotion, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
    }
    LastX = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
}
```

This code works well on desktop, but as expected, it doesn't perform so well on mobile (the platform of choice)
Interestingly it just appears as if the player follows the finger similarly to simply using:

```
this.transform.position = new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
```

Can anyone help make the first code block work correctly on mobile?

Desktop behavior (Desired)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjSzEresQI8

Mobile behavior (undesired)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OooJ_NJW7V0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Input.GetMouseButton is always true on Android (not sure about other platforms), so to force the repositioning to happen only when the user has "pressed down" on the screen I used this code:

```
if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved){
        NewX = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint (Input.mousePosition).x;
        float xMotion = (LastX - NewX) * -NavigationMultiplier / Screen.width;
        this.transform.position = new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x + xMotion, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
    }
    LastX = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition).x;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want smoother movement of the ball, kinda like in the game, not instantly teleport it to where the player touches. To do so you could use a function called `Lerp`. Read more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

To achieve this you could replace this line of code

```
this.transform.position = new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x + xMotion, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
```

with this one

```
this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, new Vector3 (this.transform.position.x , this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z),Time.deltaTime)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll definitely implement this. The problem I am still facing is the code I supplied works perfectly on desktop but fails to execute correctly on mobile...

Comment: What platform are you running it on?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The ball/player does not move upon tuch?

Comment: I would have expected that it wouldn't move, but oddly it does, only it moves as if I was using the second code block in my question...

Comment: So tapping anywhere it would immediately snap to my fingers position instead of scroll like it does on desktop...

Comment: Could you record a video and share what it looks like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139690/discussion-between-hristo-and-tiaan).