# Object Follow finger Only when it swipe on the Screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a sphere in that is moving foward and I need it to follow my finger smoothly when it swipes on the screen but only in the x axis.
I trying to make the exact movent like [Rolling Sky](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.turbochilli.rollingsky), [Color Road](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigframes.color_road)

[image]

The ball Should **follow my finger when it swipes in the x axis and move smoothly.**
Just like in the games I mention before.
I try `OnMouseDrag` and a lot of ways but it dont work correctly beacuse it dont dont follow the finger or it dont move while finger is swiping.

Comment: Could you please provide slightly more details on what you've tried and what's the exact problem?

Comment: Ok I'm going to edit the question

Comment: Try initially setting x position to `Input.mousePosition.x`?

Comment: Show us some code...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it seems you want to get the position of the user's finger and move the ball accordingly?

You could achieve this with [Touch.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html)

Example:

```
private void Update()
{
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // Get the touch data for the first finger
    Vector2 position = touch.position; // Get the position in screen-space
    Vector3 worldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position); // Convert the position to world space

    Vector3 ballPosition = ball.transform.position;
    ball.transform.position = new Vector3(worldPosition.x, ballPosition.y, ballPosition.z); // Move the ball
}
```

Comment: I must put this script on the sphere?

Comment: You can put this on the sphere if you want. You would just need to change `ball.transform` to `transform`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle the input separately from the sphere.

Put this on a script to detect the swiping on the screen.

```
    bool inputBegan = false;
    Vector2 beganPosition;

    void Update()
    {
        if (!inputBegan && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
        {
            inputBegan = true;
            beganPosition = Input.mousePosition;
        }
        else if (inputBegan && Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0))
        {
            //If you want a threshold you need to change this comparison
            if (beganPosition.x > Input.mousePosition) 
            {
                MoveBallLeft ();
            }
            else
            {
                MoveBallRight ();
            }
            inputBegan = false;
        }
    }
```

The movement of the balls you can achieve it adding or substracting `Vector2.right * movingDistance` to the sphere Transform if you want it to teleport or making the sphere move slowly using a `targetPosition` and `currentPosition` and each Update cycle add a little bit of transform distance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43169474/unity-touch-input-for-rolling-sky-x-axis-control) and setting the variable NavigationMultiplier to 10000